# Plotly graph doesn't save on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plotly

I am trying to embed the graph I have [here](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Esly.of.zero/19/#/) in my WordPress blog but am unable to view it once I refresh the page.

I am pasting the **iframe** HTML of the graph in the **Custom HTML** block in WordPress. When I click on Preview I am able to view the graph. But even after saving the edits in the draft, once I refresh the page, the graph is lost and I end up with a blank Custom HTML block.

---

This the **iframe** HTML I get from chart studio after clicking on Embed Code > iframe:

```
<iframe width="900" height="800" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="//plotly.com/~sly.of.zero/19.embed"></iframe>
```

How can this be fixed so that the graph stays saved in the blog?

Comment: Prob the problem its in the block itself. I have tested with classic content and its working fine for me. I have tested with text block from wpbakery and also works. Read this - https://publishpress.com/blog/gutenberg/add-iframes-gutenberg-blocks/ hope that will help.

Comment: How to allow iframe support in wp_kses_post() in case this could be the problem - https://gist.github.com/bjorn2404/8afe35383a29d2dd1135ae0a39dc018c